# VT-X is not showing in bios and error for haxm in android installation

Tags: android

I am using Dell Inspiron 5521R system to install android development studio. I am getting an error "VT-x is not enabled" while during haxm installation. I checked in bios, there is VT-X option is not showing. Only virtualization option is there and it is enabled already. I also checked  Hyper-V option in control panel and this one is also unchecked. but the problem is same as earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want this for the Android emulator to work properly.
Not really a solution as I tried a many things myself, but an alternative to the Android emulator is [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com). It worked for me where I never got Hyper-V to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Genymotion, it is faster, smoother than default Android Studio Emulators

1. Install [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)
2. Install [Genymotion Plugin For Android Studio](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#genymotion-plugin-for-android-studio)
3. Run Genymotion & click Red Button in the Android Studio (Which will appear after you install Genymotion Plugin for Android Studio)
4. Enjoy Developing